# Decal or paint?

Tags: frames, paint

Can someone tell me whether the visible part of the logo on the frame is a decal or a pain directly on the frame?

- If it's a decal, then where can one get a custom decal with a metallic finish?
- If it's a paint job, what are the techniques to achieve this?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think it's possible to tell from the picture, but if it's a decal, you should be able to tell as it would probably be slightly raised from the surface of the rest of the frame.  If you want a decal of similar style, contact a print or advertising company in your area (or find one online), many of them are able to make custom decals. My highschool even had the machinery for cutting custom vinyl decals, so you might want to check with local highschools or college (preferably one with a graphic design programme) to see if you can get one done by a student for cheaper.

If it's painted on, this basic method for accomplishing this is to apply the different colours in layers.  Since the frame is black, they would most likely apply the black first. Then they would apply a mask that would block out all the parts they want to remain black, and put on the next color.  The same would be done for all subsequent colours.  Then they would apply a clear coat on top for protecting the paint.

Comment: It looks pretty clearly as a paint job to me.

Comment: @Batman, I would guess paint too, but I couldn't say for 100% certainty. For all I know, the picture could be a computer rendering.  The same end result would be obtainable in both paint and decals. The only discernible difference would be the raised edge of the decal. If you wanted to achieve a similar effect on a frame you are making or refinishing, the decal would probably be the cheaper of the two options, especially if you could do the actual computer design part yourself.

Comment: +1 for the idea to have the decal made at a school. I'm at a uni with strong arts department but didn't think of asking around until your suggestion!

Comment: We used to make custom license numbers for snow machines when we were in high school using the vinyl cutter.